# feature-engine: cross-validation gives error when wrapping OneHotEncoder in SklearnTransformerWrapper

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

### Issue

I am using the [feature-engine](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/) library, and am finding that when I create an sklearn [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that uses the [SklearnTransformerWrapper](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.x_a/wrappers/Wrapper.html)  to wrap a [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), I get the following error when trying to [run cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html):

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
...
9 fits failed out of a total of 10.
The score on these train-test partitions for these parameters will be set to nan.

Below are more details about the failures:
...
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

If I do things the "old way" with an sklearn [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), I do not get the error.
I also don't get errors if I either: A) Score [without cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) or B) Don't use the categorical features (i.e. remove the one-hot encoding).

Is this an issue with `SklearnTransformerWrapper` or am I using it the wrong way?

### Code

Here is the `Pipeline` setup with `SklearnTransformerWrapper` that fails. It will work successfully if we don't use the categorical features, or if we don't do cross-validation (see comments in code):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

from feature_engine.wrappers import SklearnTransformerWrapper
from feature_engine.selection import DropFeatures


pipeline_new = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("scale_b_c", SklearnTransformerWrapper(
            transformer=StandardScaler(), 
            variables=["b", "c"]
        )
    ),
    
    # Comment out this step for cross-validation to not fail
    ("encode_a_d", SklearnTransformerWrapper(
            transformer=OneHotEncoder(drop="first", sparse=False), 
            variables=["a", "d"]
        )
    ),
    
    ("cleanup", DropFeatures(["a", "d"])),
    ("model", LinearRegression())
])

# Defined later (putting main example up front)
# Set cv to False to successfully score entire training set
do_test(df, pipeline_new, cv=True)
```

Here is the "old-style" pipeline that uses `ColumnTransformer` instead; it works correctly:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer


pipeline_old = Pipeline(steps=[
    (
        "xform", ColumnTransformer([
            ("cat", OneHotEncoder(drop="first"), ["a", "d"]),
            ("num", StandardScaler(), ["b", "c"])
        ])
    ),
    ("model", LinearRegression())
])

# Defined later (putting main example up front)
do_test(df, pipeline_old, cv=True)
```

Supporting code: implementation of the `do_test()` test function:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# do_test() implementation
def do_test(df, pipeline, cv=True):
    X = df.drop(columns=["y"])
    y = df[["y"]]
       
    if cv:
        return cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv=10)
    else:
        pipeline.fit(X, y)
        y_pred = pipeline.predict(X)        
        return mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
```

Supporting code: sample data creation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create sample data
n = 20000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"][np.random.randint(4)] for i in range(n)],
    "b": [np.random.random() * 100 for i in range(n)],
    "c": [np.random.random() * 200 for i in range(n)],
    "d": [["east", "west"][np.random.randint(2)] for i in range(n)],
})

def make_y(x):
    add_1 = 100 if x.a in ["alpha", "beta"] else 200
    add_2 = 100 if x.d in ["east"] else 300

    return 2 * x.b + 3 * x.c + 2 * add_1 + 5 * add_2 + np.random.normal(10)

df["y"] = df.apply(make_y, axis=1)
```

**Note**: I am not doing train/test separation, in order to keep the question shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the output that @AlwaysRightNeverLeft gives suggests an issue with the indexes: when cross-validating, the dataframes will have nonstandard indexes, and when `SklearnTransformerWrapper` merges the one-hot encoded array to the original data, it does an "outer join".

Comment: Thanks for diagnosis here: 
https://github.com/feature-engine/feature_engine/issues/368#issuecomment-1026315846
Taking a look now

Answer (score 3):

It is simple enough to verify that `"encode_a_d"` step in the pipe with `SklearnTransformerWrapper` produces  NaNs during cross-validation:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits = 10)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index], X.loc[test_index]
    X_train_pipe = pipeline_new["encode_a_d"].fit_transform(pipeline_new["scale_b_c"].fit_transform(X_train))
    X_test_pipe = pipeline_new["encode_a_d"].fit_transform(pipeline_new["scale_b_c"].fit_transform(X_test))
    print(X_train_pipe.isnull().any().any(), X_test_pipe.isnull().any().any())
```

It seems that it doubles the number of rows, and puts NaNs for features `['b', 'c']` where one-hot-encoded features formed from `['a', 'd']` have their usual values, and vice versa. As to why this happens - I have no idea, `feature-engine` may be at fault, but from my experience it may well be some wicked trickery on `cross_val_score`'s part.